# How to specify connection release modes in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

How to specify connection release modes in Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `hibernate.connection.release_mode` property of the session factory. [see here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-connection-release)